# The instance of entity type 'Shipment' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 46}' is already being tracked

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to link `Shipments` to `Road` using a clean database, with fresh data unlinked, first time trying to relate these 2 entities.

```
public class Road
{
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }

public ShipmentMode ShipmentMode { get; set; }

public string RoadName { get; set; }

public virtual List<Shipment> Shipments { get; set; }
}   


public void SaveToDatabase()
{
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        foreach (var road in this.Roads)
        {
            road.Shipments.ForEach(shipment => shipment = db.Shipments.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == shipment.Id));

            var input = db.Roads.Add(road);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

At the line `var input = db.Roads.Add(road);` it will throw the error `Message  "The instance of entity type 'Shipment' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 46}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'`.

I had this error before, fixed it but I rearranged the code and now it's back to throwing this error. I am just trying to get Shipments to link to Road.

Comment: Why are you adding?  Linking two object does not mean that one has to be added to the other.

Comment: @jdweng Lane is the object that is newly being saved to the database. Shipments is what I am trying to link to that new object which is already saved in the database.

Comment: You have a primary key which can only be in the database once.  You are trying to add the key a second time.   If you are trying to link you have to search for primary key and then UPDATE the object in the existing key

Comment: @jdweng Can you check my answer for a better solution? I am not familiar with using Update.

Comment: The issue is you are adding the same "ID" twice into the database.  The Id is an Identity.  I can't tell from the code why you have the same ID more than once. You may want to use GroupBy to combine the common IDs to avoid this issue.

Comment: @jdweng Shipments is passed into the class object from the database. I then create Road objects from the Shipments and include those shipments in the List of the road object.

Comment: Then ID should not be a key or you have one ID and the shipments get added to the list like in your answer getRoad.Shipments.AddRange(shipments).. You need to create only one Road with an ID and then the shipments get added as a Range.

Answer (score 0):

This code below has worked for me. If anyone has a better solution, please feel free to post.

```
public void SaveToDatabase()
{
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        foreach (var road in this.Roads)
        {
            var shipments = road.Shipments;

            road.Shipments = null;

            var input = db.Roads.Add(road);

            db.SaveChanges();

            var getRoad = db.Lanes.Include(p => p.Shipments).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == input.Entity.Id);
            getRoad.Shipments.AddRange(shipments);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternative solution

```
public void SaveToDatabase()
{
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        foreach (var road in this.Roads)
        {

            db.UpdateRange(road.Shipments);

            var input = db.Roads.Add(road);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```